# Should I use an <aside> tag? If so, how do I place it correctly?

Tags: html, css

I'm building my first website, a wedding website for my cousin, that will have basic sections such as the wedding, reception, bridal parties, RSVP, etc. and I plan to have a "menu" of sorts on each page to direct users where to go and provide links to how to get there.

I plan on using an `<aside>` for this, but I'm not sure if that's the best option. If it is, how can I properly format it to stay, let's say, 10px away from the `.content` object? [As seen here,](http://jsfiddle.net/so85ro7e/) the outline of the aside overlaps the gray box of the `.content`.

Comment: Where will you be hosting the site? what web building tools do you have (can you use).

Comment: @ErstwhileIII: I’m not sure that matters for purposes of deciding which tag to use or how to fix the layout of a site.

Comment: You’re partly being bitten by the CSS box model. While it’s not a good long-term solution, try applying `box-sizing: border-box;`. If that fixes it, you know that’s the problem.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII I have no idea what I plan on using, I haven't even thought that far ahead yet, just trying to get some basic HTML together.

Comment: @icktoofay I just added that and it works great. No matter how small I make the window, the two won't overlap. Ideally, I'd like to have that distance be the same no matter the size of the window. Is that possible when using a liquid layout? What if I used a fixed width layout instead?

Comment: You might try using a Google "site" .. you won;t need to get too low lwvel and you will be able to do all the things you were mentioning

Comment: @ErstwhileIII If my end objective were to build a website, I would definitely go that route. There are tons of tools out there (like Google Sites) that can help me build websites like that. But, the real purpose for this project was to learn HTML/CSS. It's a field of CS I want to learn better, eventually to possibly create end-user interfaces for databases and the like. Thanks for the recommendation, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the aside tag correctly, but that wasn't really the problem to begin with.

The overlap you were seeing was caused by floating the aside to the left. Floating an element removes it from the normal document flow.

Rather than using `float: left;` try using `display: inline-block;`

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/so85ro7e/8/)

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
img.banner {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
img.title {
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
figcaption {
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: center;
}
header {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}
nav {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.content {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
article {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  margin: 10px;
}
aside {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 12%;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
footer {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" class="banner" alt="Banner" />
  <header>
    <p>Tom and Suzy's Wedding</p>
  </header>
  <aside>
  </aside>
  <div class="content">
    <figure>
      <article>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/500" class="title" alt="Kitten" />
        <figcaption>August 1, 2015</figcaption>
      </article>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<aside>` tag defines some content aside from the content it is placed in and therefore should be related to the **surrounding** content of your webpage (in your case it's the wedding, bridal parties, etc.). Using an `<aside>` tag for you is perfectly fine.
If you want the `<aside>` tag to be precisely 10 **pixels** away from the `.content` object, replace this line of code you wrote in your **CSS** for your `<aside>` tag:

```
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
```

with this line of code:

```
padding-right: 10px;
```

Hopefully that helped!